# Change Month and Year in a datetime

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a datetime field in my query.

```
Select Account, Period, JEDate
From table
```

I would like to replace the year of the "JEDate" datetime field with a Parameter "@Year" (int).
I would also like to replace the month with the "Period" (int) field.

Example:
If the JEDate was 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 (or any other date), the year was 2013 and the month was 2, I would like the JEDate to be 2013-02-01 00:00:00.000.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName
SET JEDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(@Year as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(Period as VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + '01', 102)
WHERE JEDate IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9cdd/9/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that adds the difference between the original year and month, and the new year and month:

select dateadd(year, @year-Year(JEDATE), dateadd(month, Period-Month(JEDATE), JEDATE))